# Using reference not found in HomeController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on an MVC3 project where I'm using an external library in my view to perform a specific function. However, when I try to reference the same library in my controller code, it can't be found (cue the "the type or namespace cannot be found" error).

Is there anything I can do to fix this? If not, is there a way that I can pull in a function/helper from my view into the controller code?

For example, in my Home/Index.cshtml file I'm referencing a library like so:

```
@using Amazon.S3.Model;
```

and I'm referencing the same library in my HomeController.cs file like so:

```
using Amazon.S3.Model;
```

Comment: Use the full namespace (i.e. `Full.Name.Space.Class`) or a using statement `using Full.Name.Space;`?

Comment: how about showing us how you add the reference in the view and in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

It's probable that in the Web.config inside your views folder there is an explicit reference to the `Amazon.S3` library, but do you have a project reference for it? Check the references folder in your project and make sure that a reference exists.

Comment: There isn't a reference to the library in Views/Web.config but there is in the project web.config. The reference is there in the project - I can use the library fine in my views, just not my controllers for some reason!

Comment: Does the reference in your Web.config have a specific version, and if so is the version the same as the one in your project references? Conflicting versions can cause this problem as only one version of the .dll will be in your bin folder so whichever reference is incorrect won't work.